# Prove from the generating function that even index Legendre polynomials are even functions.

Tags: generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

At this link: [http://www.phy.ohio.edu/~phillips/Mathmethods/Notes/Chapter8.pdf](http://www.phy.ohio.edu/%7Ephillips/Mathmethods/Notes/Chapter8.pdf)

The author writes that one can prove from the generating function of Legendre polynomials that $P_{2n}$ are all even and $P_{2n+1}$ are odd, by generalizing the argument for finding $P_n(-1)$.

I tried doing that, but can't quite see how the generalization works.

Of course we should start from considering $(1+2xt+t^2)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(-x)t^n$.  The argument given for $P_n(-1)$ involved simplifying to a form with a recognizable Taylor expansion.

I would guess that we should write this in something like the form

$$ (1\pm z^2)^{-1/2} $$

If we choose $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$ this has expansion $\sum\binom{-1/2}{n}1^{-1/2-n}(-z^2)^n$.  Looks promising, so we try to wrangle the given generating function into that form.  It is

$$(1-x^2+x^2+2xt + t^2)^{-1/2} = ([1-x^2]-[-(x+t)^2])^{-1/2} $$

$$ = (1-x^2)^{-1/2}\left(1-\left[\frac{-(x+t)^2}{1-x^2}\right]\right)^{-1/2} $$

$$ = (1-x^2)^{-1/2}\left(1-\left[-\left(\frac{x+t}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2\right]\right)^{-1/2} $$

---

So (1) this just feels wrong.  It feels way too over-complicated and drifting off course.  (2) I'm not sure what to do with that factor of $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$.  (3) Even if I could get all the i's dotted and t's crossed, this looks like both $x$ and $t$ will, when expanded as a Maclauren series, be under the exponent of $n$.  So then what do you do, when you should only have $t^n$ and then a coefficient function of $x$?

I feel that this simply must not be the way to go, but don't see an alternative.

Comment: *Hint*: By considering $[(1-2xt+t^2)(1+2xt+t^2)]^{-1/2}$, prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n P_{n-k}(x)P_k(-x)$ is even (in $x$).  Now use $P_0=1$ and induct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider according to the referenced paper the bivariate function
\begin{align*}
g(t,x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Here we use $g(t,x)$ to show that even indexed Legendre polynomials $P_{2n}$ are even.

> We obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{g(t,x)+g(-t,x)}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)(-t)^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{2n}(x)t^{2n}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> It follows from (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{2n}(x)t^n}\tag{3}
> &=g(t,x)+g(-t,x)\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2xt+t^2}}\\
> &=g(-t,-x)+g(t,-x)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{2n}(-x)t^{2n}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim that $P_{2n}$ are even follows by comparing coefficients of $t$ in (3) and (4).

A similar calculation could be done to show that odd indexed Legendre polynomials $P_{2n+1}$ are odd.

Comment: Small question: Shouldn't (2) have a factor of 2 on it?  I assume the logic is that the odd powers of $t$ cancel, so shouldn't the even powers combine?

Comment: @Addem: Yes, many thanks - mistake corrected.